# Insert item to desktop right-click menufrom shell extension

Tags: c++, winapi, shell, atl, explorer

I've written a windows explorer shell extension using VS2010 and ATL, registered under HKLM\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers to add my commands under context menu.

All is working as expected, but I want to add a context-menu entry which shows up if and only if user has right-clicked on desktop, like windows 7 defaults "gadgets, personalize, etc".

I've tried this, but does not work (does not match):

```
if (GetForegroundWindow () == GetDesktopWindow ()) {
   // code here
}
```

Any toughts on how this can be done ?

I've also tried using SHGetFolderPath() with CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY and do a _tcsicmp(), this works, but does show up even if desktop directory is opened in a normal windows explorer window, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register it under `HKCR\DesktopBackground\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`

Comment: Yes, this exactly what I did (I will edit my question), however I already said that extension works , I ask how to make it show up if and only if user right click inside the desktop area, not in every background of every directory, which is the behavior until now.

Comment: @modoran Look more closely. Stefan said `DesktopBackground` but you said `Directory\Background`.

Comment: Ok, I will mark Stefan answer as the solution. Problem was solved.